# sql Trigger: select the FK from another table before insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two database tables.

1. `tblTeams`: `PK TeamID`,`TeamName`
2. `tblMatches`: `PK match id`,`FK HomeTeam`,`FK AwayTeam,Score`.

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I am importing rows through the Wizard from a `.csv` file. The columns in the `csv` are `hometeam`,`awayteam`,`score`. Thus, before inserting in the `tblMatches`, I want a trigger that finds the FK of the team and inserts in the `tblMatches` the foreign key and not the name.

Any help with that please.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tblmatches_BeforeInsert
ON tblmatches
BEFORE INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT  tblmatches
    SELECT  teamName
    FROM    tblmatches
    WHERE   tblTeams.id = ?i dont know here what to insert? 
END
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Here is what i tried. I am new to triggers :)

Comment: how are you reading the `.csv` file?

Comment: With the Import Wizard of sql server 2008. But i think it doesn't matters. Because the trigger is going to be executed on insert of a row, right?

Comment: @user1292656, just wanted to know if you are using any high-level language to parse the CSV and insert the records.

Comment: There's no `BEFORE INSERT` in SQL Server

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I want a trigger that finds the FK of the team and inserts in the tblMatches the foreign key and not the name"?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, for a trigger to be called on tblMatches, you need to supply values for all the columns in that table and only for the columns in that table which means, you cannot pass a team name to a trigger so that it can be used to resolve the team ID.

If I were to do it, I would just create a table to insert the raw data as is, let the import wizard write records into this table, define a trigger on this table to insert records into the two derived tables viz. tblTeams, tblMatches. ([SQL Server Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx))

My attempt at writing one (didn't get a chance to verify as I don't have SQL server)

```
CREATE TRIGGER teams.process ON teams
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @homeTeamId INT
    DECLARE @awayTeamId INT
    DECLARE @maxTeamId INT
    DECLARE @matchId INT

    SELECT @maxTeamId = 0
    SELECT @maxTeamId = ISNULL(MAX(teamId), 0) from tblTeams

    --- Check if home team has already been inserted into the table.
    SELECT @homeTeamId = -1
    SELECT 
        @homeTeamId = teamId 
    FROM 
        tblTeams t
        JOIN inserted i
        ON t.teamName = i.hometeam
    IF (@homeTeamId = -1) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @homeTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
        SELECT @maxTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
        INSERT INTO tblTeams SELECT @homeTeamId, i.hometeam FROM inserted i
    END

    --- Check if away team has already been inserted into the table.
    SELECT @awayTeamId = -1
    SELECT 
        @awayTeamId = teamId 
    FROM 
        tblTeams t
        JOIN inserted i
        ON t.teamName = i.awayteam
    IF (@awayTeamId = -1) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @awayTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
        SELECT @maxTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
        INSERT INTO tblTeams SELECT @awayTeamId, i.awayteam FROM inserted i
    END

    -- insert a record into the matches table with the home team ID and away team ID.
    SELECT @matchId = 0
    SELECT @matchId = ISNULL(MAX(MatchId), 0) FROM tblMatches
    INSERT INTO tblMatches 
    SELECT @matchId + 1, @homeTeamId, @awayTeamId, i.score 
    FROM inserted i
END
```

Comment: Hmm so i have to use after insert. Can you help me with this Trigger?

Comment: @user1292656, I tried to write one as per the details in the question. You may want to verify and use it accordingly.

Comment: I am getting an error Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure process, Line 46
Invalid column name 'score'.

Comment: @user1292656, that's because I should use the `inserted` table to get the score of the current record from teams. Edited my trigger definition. Please check now.

Comment: hmm still something goes wrong. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure process, Line 46
The multi-part identifier "i.score" could not be bound.

Comment: The "inserted" in the last INSERT was not qualified as 'i' and hence the error. Updated the script.

Comment: Hm i think we are too close. On the following line:   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblTeams] SELECT @homeTeamId, i.hometeam FROM inserted i. I get the following error. An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.tblTeamslist' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON. I set the identity_insert on, but what means 'when a column list is used?'

Comment: ok i correct it INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblTeamslist](teamid,teamname) and the query runs successfuly.  But is not triggering on insert :)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different representation in the table then you'll probably have to implement a view, and perform the inserts via it, rather than the base table.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE realMatches (
    MatchID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null, /* Identity? */
    HomeTeamID int not null,
    AwayTeamID int not null,
    Score int not null, /* int? */
    constraint PK_realMatches PRIMARY KEY (MatchID),
    constraint FK_Matches_HomeTeams (HomeTeamID) references tblTeams (TeamID),
    constraint FK_Matches_AwayTeams (AwayTeamID) references tblTeams (TeamID)
)
GO
CREATE VIEW tblMatches
AS
    SELECT
        MatchID,
        ht.TeamName as HomeTeam,
        at.TeamName as AwayTeam,
        Score
    FROM
        realMatches m
           inner join
        tblTeams ht
           on
               m.HomeTeamID = ht.TeamID
           inner join
        tblTeams at
           on
               m.AwayTeamID = at.TeamID
GO
CREATE TRIGGER T_Matches ON tblMatches
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
     SET NOCOUNT ON

     INSERT INTO realMatches (HomeTeamID,AwayTeamID,Score)
     SELECT ht.TeamID,at.TeamID,i.Score
     FROM
        inserted i
           inner join
        tblTeam ht
           on
              i.HomeTeam = ht.TeamName
           inner join
        tblTeam at
           on
              i.AwayTeam = at.TeamName
```

You can now (assuming that "A Team" and "Team America" exist in `tblTeams`):

```
INSERT INTO tblMatches (HomeTeam,AwayTeam,Score)
VALUES ('A Team','Team America',19)
```

Of course, this doesn't (yet) deal with any *updates* which attempt to change a team in the matches table, nor what to do if a team doesn't yet exist in `tblTeam`, but you've not asked about those yet.